# My code is not printing

Tags: java, database, class, methods, printing

my code (reads a text file, uses a class I built to sort through the data, and then outputs onto console), is not printing anything!  Can somebody please tell me where my little mistake is!  I know the VERY end is not finished yet.  Please help!!!!!!!!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project02 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    // Enter file name
    System.out.print("Enter database file name: ");
    String fileName = in.nextLine();
    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        System.out.println();
        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            Product p = new Product();
            String title = inputFile.nextLine();
            String code = inputFile.nextLine();
            Integer quantity = inputFile.nextInt();
            Double price = inputFile.nextDouble();
            inputFile.nextLine();
            String type = inputFile.nextLine();
            Integer userReview = inputFile.nextInt();
            // read in title
            p.setName(title);
            // read in iCode
            p.setInventoryCode(code);
            // read in quantity
            p.setQuantity(quantity);
            // read in price
            p.setPrice(price);
            // read in type
            p.setType(type);
            // read in user reviews
            while (!userReview.equals(-1)) {
                p.addUserRating(userReview);
                userReview = inputFile.nextInt();
            }
            if (inputFile.hasNext()) {
                inputFile.nextLine();
            }
        }
        inputFile.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("There was an error reading from " + fileName);
    }

}

private static String highRating(ArrayList<Product> p) {
    int highestR = 0;
    int indexOfHighestR = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++) {
        int rating = p.get(i).getAvgUserRating();
        if (p.get(i).getAvgUserRating() > highestR) {
            highestR = p.get(i).getAvgUserRating();
            indexOfHighestR = i;
        }
    }
    int zero = 0;
    String Star = " ";

    while (highestR > zero) {
        Star = Star + "*";
        zero--;
    }
    String highestRateTitle = p.get(indexOfHighestR).getName() + "  ("
            + Star + ")";

    return highestRateTitle;
}

private static String lowestRating(ArrayList<Product> p) {
    int lowestR = 0;
    int indexOfLowestR = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++) {
        int rating = p.get(i).getAvgUserRating();
        if (p.get(i).getAvgUserRating() < lowestR) {
            lowestR = p.get(i).getAvgUserRating();
            indexOfLowestR = i;
        }
    }
    int zero = 0;
    String Star = " ";

    while (lowestR > zero) {
        Star = Star + "*";
        zero--;
    }
    String highestRateTitle = p.get(indexOfLowestR).getName() + "  ("
            + Star + ")";

    return highestRateTitle;
}

private static double maxDollar(ArrayList<Product> p) {
    double largestP = 0;
    int indexOfLargestP = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++) {
        double price = p.get(i).getPrice();
        if (p.get(i).getPrice() > largestP) {
            largestP = p.get(i).getPrice();
            indexOfLargestP = i;
        }
    }
    return largestP;
}

private static int minDollar(ArrayList<Product> p) {
    double smallestP = p.get(0).getPrice();
    int indexOfSmallestP = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++) {
        if (p.get(i).getPrice() < smallestP) {
            smallestP = p.get(i).getPrice();
            indexOfSmallestP = i;
        }
    }
    return indexOfSmallestP;
}

private static void inventoryList(ArrayList<Product> p) {
    int count = 
    System.out.println("Product Summary Report: ");
    System.out
            .println("------------------------------------------------------------");
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        System.out.println("Title: " + p.get(i).getName());
        System.out.println("I Code: " + p.get(i).getInventoryCode());
        System.out.println("Product Type: " + p.get(i).getType());
        System.out.println("Rating: " + p.get(i).getAvgUserRating());
        System.out.println("# Rat.: " + p.get(i).getUserRatingCount());
        System.out.println("Quantity: " + p.get(i).getQuantity());
        System.out.println("Price: " + p.get(i).getPrice());
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out
            .println("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
    // System.out.println("Total products in database: " + count);
    System.out.println("Highest total dollar item: "
            + p.get(maxDollar(p)) + " ($"+ p.(maxDollar(p)) + ")");
    System.out.println("Smallest quantity item: "
            + p.get(minQuantity(quantities)) + " ("
            + types.get(minQuantity(quantities)) + ")");
    System.out.println("Lowest total dollar item: "
            + titles.get(minDollar(prices)) + " ($"
            + prices.get(minDollar(prices)) + ")");
    System.out
            .println("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
}
```

Comment: Please no SHOUTING. Can you provide an example of the "database" file?

Comment: The Shawshank Redemption
C0000001
100
19.95
DVD
4
5
3
1
-1
The Dark Knight
C0000003
50
19.95
DVD
5
2
3
-1
Casablanca
C0000007
137
9.95
DVD
5
4
5
3
-1
The Girl With The Dragon Tattoo
C0000015
150
14.95
Book
4
4
2
-1
Vertigo
C0000023
55
9.95
DVD
5
5 
3
5
2
4
-1
A Game of Thrones
C0000019
100
8.95
Book
-1

Comment: What do you think your program should print, and why?

Comment: Try calling your `inventoryList()` method somewhere. Of course, first you'll need to fix it so it compiles.

Comment: I am having a lot of trouble with my inventoryList() method.  This is my first time writing code like this and I do not know how to for example get the total number of movie titles (there should be six).  Another thing I am confused on is how to call the proper things from the private methods I wrote above.

Comment: Can you, please, add that data to your question and format correctly so you code can read it

Comment: You're not adding `p` to `products`...

Comment: I debugged my program.  And the program is reading the text file.  I am just having issues printing it correctly.

Comment: Where should I be looking when you say i am not adding p to products

Comment: When you say you are having issues printing it correctly, precisely where are your print statements? **hint** look at your `inventoryList()` method.

Comment: If I upload my class would that help at all? I know that is right though...

Comment: I want to create a method that does all my printing and then call that method in the main method.  I am having issues within my print method.

Comment: Well, I assuming you want to add the `Product`, `p`, you just created to the `List` of `products`, so you should do that before the next cycle of the `while-loop` I guess

Comment: MadProgrammer is there a way I can contact you to send you the entire code? No errors are being shown and I am not understanding this.

Comment: You could post it on pastebin.  Just make sure to include the data in the right format

Comment: Product Class: http://pastebin.com/EdGYFv6N

Comment: Product Inventory List Buildup: http://pastebin.com/1169QaZ1

Answer (score 1):

## First...

After you've create an instance of `Product`, `p`, you will need to add it to the `products` list, otherwise you will lose it's reference and won't be able to use it again...

```
while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
    Product p = new Product();
    //...
    products.add(p);
    if (inputFile.hasNext()) {
        inputFile.nextLine();
    }
}
```

## Second...

You will need to pass the `products` `List` to something that want's to use/display the information, for example `inventoryList`...

But wait, that's not working?

If we take a closer look at the the `inventoryList` method...

```
    int count = 0;
    //...
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
```

We can see that `count` is always `0`, so it will never print anything!  You should be using `p.size()` instead, which is the actually length of the `products` `List`

```
    //...
    for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++) {
```